# Is there an option setting in about:config to let firefox always maximized at startup?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to let the firefox window always maxmized at startup,not full screen. But I don't want to use Javascript or something else to implement it. I want to know if there is a simple option setting in the about:config to achive this? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

There is no option in `about:config` to start firefox in fullscreen.

You can try to edit the `localstore.rdf` file in the Firefox profile folder and find the section with `browser.xul#main-window` and add/change the `sizemode="fullscreen"` parameter.

```
<RDF:Description RDF:about="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#main-window"
        height="843"
        width="1145"
        screenX="527"
        screenY="19"
        sizemode="fullscreen" />
```

To access Firefox profile folder, type `about:support` on addressbar and find option to view the folder under Application Basics section. The option may be "Show Folder" (Windows), "Open Directory" (Linux) or "Open Containing Folder" depending on OS and version of firefox.

Close firefox before editing the file. Otherwise the change will be reverted.

NB: The original author of this [answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/972412) disclaims that he/she is not sure about its working on Mac.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I don't want the full screen mode, and I just want the Firefox window maxmized.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to edit the `xulstore.json` file as described here: https://gist.github.com/hoangtranwork/fbd308f326a741109f8eb03a9990a839

1. Get the profile folder location in `about:support` page
2. Edit the file `xulstore.json` found in the above folder. It's a json file and we need only to edit the key `main-window` to something like this:

   `"main-window":{"screenX":"0","screenY":"0","width":"1920","height":"1080","sizemode":"maximized"}`

NOTE:
- Step 2 should be done when Firefox is not open, as it seems that the file get updated when Firefox closes.
- Sometimes you need to put negative value to `screenX` if the windows is still shifted abit from the screen edge.